# how to call a view method to a model in zendframework

Tags: php, zend-framework

hello I just want to ask whether we can call a view method to a model? I know that we can call it on our controller in zend framework. Like if I want to call the url method of view on my controller I can call it like this

```
$this->view->url(array(),'');
```

and on the view we just can call it by

```
$this->url(array(),'');
```

But When I tried to call the same method on my model by

```
$this->view->url(array(),'');
```

it generates an error of call to undefined method `url`. 
Now I want to ask whether it is possible to call view method to a model? If yes then how? What Am I doing wrong. 
Thanks

Comment: FYI, you should use the URL action helper in your controllers, ie `$this->_helper->url->url(array())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the URL helper, why not inject / lazy load it in your model, eg

```
class Application_Model_MyModel
{
    /**
     * @var Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url
     */
    private $urlHelper;

    public function setUrlHelper(Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url $helper)
    {
        $this->urlHelper = $helper;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Lazy load URL action helper
     *
     * @return Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Url
     */
    protected function getUrlHelper()
    {
        if (null === $this->urlHelper) {
            $this->setUrlHelper(
                Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('url'));
        }
        return $this->urlHelper;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $url = $this->getUrlHelper()->url(array(), null);
    }
```

This way, you can either pass the helper to your model from the controller...

```
$model = new Application_Model_MyModel;
$model->setUrlHelper($this->_helper->getHelper('url'));
```

or let the lazy loader fetch it statically from the helper broker.

Comment: This is exactly What I was needing. +1 for detailed answer. I dont know any thing about helpers so I should do it now. Only one thing to be clarify I am unable to understand the term Lazy load url that you have used?

Comment: @awais-qarni Please refer this link for detailed explanation of [lazy-load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading).

Comment: @RakeshS Thanks dude. Now got every thing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should not need access to the view from a model. If you do so, it might be a smell, a sign that something in your design is flawed. The view is not even a neighbouring layer of the model, which makes it even smellier.

In general your controller should pass to the model everything the model needs to fullfill its duty. If you really need to access parts of the view because you just decide to take a shortcut (which sometimes is necessary even on the principles of DRY/KISS) then provide these parts as view helpers (decoupled) and use lazy loading in your models as Phil explains in his answer. This is a good way to create the additional overhead only in case of need!

Comment: +1 for your good explanation. I do agree with your point of view about calling methods of views to a model is a wrong practice. But I have tangled in a situation where I have to return the url from my model Thats why I have asked.